# Simple geometric proof of parallel lines cut by transversals

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Three parallel lines a,b and c are cut by transversal ABC. I need to prove that, if $AB = BC$, then $A'B' = B'C'$. I've made this drawing in geogebra. Any idea of what theorem is this? Could you guys give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you given any more information other than $AB = BC$?

Comment: Consider the parallelogram ADEC and prove that $\triangle A'DB'  \cong \triangle B'EC'$. Alternatively, you could use **Thales' theorem**, but I would go with the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this is called "intercept theorem".

To distinguish it from the "intercept theorem (for triangles)", some call it "extended intercept theorem" or "generalized intercept theorem".

There are 2 ways of proving it:-

(1) by using properties of a parallelogram; or

(2) Using "intercept theorem (for triangles)" [twice] after joining A'C.